# how to create table in sqlite data base programmatically

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i am new to sqlite on iphone.

i am to creating a data base using terminal.Now i need to create a table through code in my application.

my code for that is

```
-(BOOL)createtable:(NSString *)tableName {
    BOOL ret;
    int rc;
    // SQL to create new table

    NSString *sql_str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE %@ (pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , ItemName VARCHAR(100), Quantity INTEGER DEFAULT 0, Status BOOLEAN,Type VARCHAR(100))", tableName];

    const char *sqlStatement = (char *)[sql_str UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"query %s",sqlStatement);

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &stmt, NULL);

    ret = (rc == SQLITE_OK);
    if (ret)
    { // statement built, execute
        rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
        ret = (rc == SQLITE_DONE);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt); // free statement
    NSLog(@"creating table");
    return ret;
}
```

but table is not created, i am checking that database in mozilla sqlite manager.

can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the 'database' variable contains the exact path to the database you're checking in sqlite manager?

Comment: yes, i add database which in iphone simulator applications,in documents i found my database, i add it to sqlite manager

Comment: This function is returning `TRUE`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use sqlite3_exec() method instead of sqlite3_step().

sqlite3_exec() will execute whatever the query you have given.

I am sure, It will definitely help you.

```
-(BOOL)createNewTable
{
    NSArray *array=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath=[array objectAtIndex:0];

filePath =[filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourdatabase.db"];

NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

BOOL success = NO;
if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) 
{
    success =YES;
}
if (!success) 
{
    NSString *path2=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourdatabase.db"];
    success =[manager copyItemAtPath:path2 toPath:filePath error:nil];
}
createStmt = nil;
NSString *tableName=@"SecondTable";
if (sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    if (createStmt == nil) {

        NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"create table %@(rollNo integer, name text)",tableName];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &createStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            return NO;
        }
        sqlite3_exec(database, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);
        return YES;
    }
}
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im posting an answer as well because there is no error handling in your example and that seems valuable

INIT DB:

```
    self.databasePath = [[NSString alloc]init];
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDB.db"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

    self.databasePath = writableDBPath;

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: self.databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Database Opened");

            sqlite3_close(myDB);

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }else {
//        NSLog(@"File exist");
    }
```

MAKE CALL TO CREATE TABLES:

```
const char *dbpath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *charsTableNameQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %@(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, charName TEXT)",charsTableName];

        int results = 0;

        //create all chars tables
        const char *charsTableNameQuerySQL = [charsTableNameQuery UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt * charsTableNameStatment = nil;
        results = sqlite3_exec(myDB, charsTableNameQuerySQL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (results != SQLITE_DONE) {
            const char *err = sqlite3_errmsg(tekkenDB);
            NSString *errMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",err];
            if (![errMsg isEqualToString:@"not an error"]) {
                NSLog(@"createTables-chartables error: %@",errMsg);
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(charsTableNameStatment);
        sqlite3_close(myDB);

        return TRUE;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"database not opened");
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call in receive memmory warning

```
(IBAction)findContact:(UIButton *)sender {
  const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];
  sqlite3_stmt *statement;

  if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &contactDB)== SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ADDRESS,PHONE FROM CONTACTS WHERE NAME = \"%@\"",_name.text];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement)== SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            _address.text = addressField;
            NSString *phoneField = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            _phoneNo.text = phoneField;
            _status.text = @"Match Found";
        }else{
            _status.text = @"Match not found";
            _address.text = @"";
            _phoneNo.text = @"";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

- create objc file with bridging header (YOURFILENAME-Bridging-Header.h)
- paste this code in your CustomDB.m file. ("CustomDB.m" <- this is my file name)

  ```
   #import "CustomDB.h"

          @implementation CustomDB

          - (void)createWith:(NSString *)strFileName;
          {
              NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
              NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];

              dbPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFileName];
              NSLog(@"%@",dbPathString);
              char *error;

              NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
              if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString]) {
                  const char *dbPath = [dbPathString UTF8String];

                  //creat db here
                  if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &personDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
                      const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSONS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, AGE TEXT)";
                      sqlite3_exec(personDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error);
                      sqlite3_close(personDB);
                  }
              }
          }
          -(void)insertInToDB:(NSString *)strQuery{
              char *error;
              if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &personDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
                  NSString *inserStmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strQuery];
                  const char *insert_stmt = [inserStmt UTF8String];

                  if (sqlite3_exec(personDB, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK) {
                      NSLog(@"Insert successfully");
                  }
                  sqlite3_close(personDB);
              }



          }
          -(NSArray *)selectFromDB:(NSString *)strQuery{
              sqlite3_stmt *statement;
              id result;
              NSMutableArray *thisArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

              if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &personDB)==SQLITE_OK) {

                  NSString *querySql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM PERSONS"];
                  const char* query_sql = [querySql UTF8String];

                  if (sqlite3_prepare(personDB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
                      while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                          NSMutableDictionary *thisDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                          for (int i = 0 ; i < sqlite3_column_count(statement) ; i++) {
                              if(sqlite3_column_type(statement,i) == SQLITE_NULL){
                                  continue;
                              }
                              if (sqlite3_column_decltype(statement,i) != NULL &&
                                  strcasecmp(sqlite3_column_decltype(statement,i),"Boolean") == 0) {
                                  result = [NSNumber numberWithBool:(BOOL)sqlite3_column_int(statement,i)];
                              } else if (sqlite3_column_type(statement,i) == SQLITE_INTEGER) {
                                  result = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)sqlite3_column_int(statement,i)];
                              } else if (sqlite3_column_type(statement,i) == SQLITE_FLOAT) {
                                  result = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)sqlite3_column_double(statement,i)];
                              } else {
                                  if((char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,i) != NULL){
                                      result = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,i)];
                                      [thisDict setObject:result
                                                   forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_column_name(statement,i)]];
                                      result = nil;
                                  }
                              }
                              if (result) {
                                  [thisDict setObject:result
                                               forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_column_name(statement,i)]];
                              }
                          }
                          [thisArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:thisDict]];
                      }
                  }
              }
              return thisArray;
          }
          -(void)deleteFromDB:(NSString *)strQuery{
              char *error;

              if (sqlite3_exec(personDB, [strQuery UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK) {
                  NSLog(@"Person deleted");
              }
          }
          @end

  // paste this code in your CustomDB.h file. ("CustomDB.h" <- this is my file name)

  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  #import <sqlite3.h>

  @interface CustomDB : NSObject
  {
      sqlite3 *personDB;
      NSString *dbPathString;
  }
  -(void)createWith:(NSString *)strFileName;
  -(void)insertInToDB:(NSString*)strQuery;
  -(NSArray *)selectFromDB:(NSString *)strQuery;
  -(void)deleteFromDB:(NSString*)strQuery;
  @end
  ```

Don't forget to add this line in your bridging header -> #import "CustomDB.h" and adding sqlite framework in your project... :)

Enjoy these create,insert,delete and select queries in sqlite database :)

Answer (score -1):

NSString *docsDict;
    NSArray *dirPath;

```
//Get the Dictionary
dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
docsDict = dirPath[0];
NSLog(@"Path : %@",docsDict);

//Build the path to keep the database
_database = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDict stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myUser.sql"]];

NSFileManager *fileMngr= [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if([fileMngr fileExistsAtPath:_database] == NO)
    {
     const char *dbpath = [_database UTF8String];

  if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK)
       {
        char *errorMassage;
        const char *sql_statement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FIRSTNAME TEXT, LASTNAME TEXT , MOBILENO TEXT)";

     if (sqlite3_exec(_DB,sql_statement,NULL,NULL,&errorMassage)!= SQLITE_OK)
        {
            [self showUIAlertWithMessage:@"Failed to create the table" andTitle:@"error"];
        }
            sqlite3_close(_DB);
     }
  else
       {
        [self showUIAlertWithMessage:@"Failed to open/create the table" andTitle:@"Error"];
       }
}
```